# How to break a long python line (assignment) with very long variable names

Tags: python, flake8

This is not my code, but I'm asked to fix some flake8 lint errors.

There's a line in the code that looks like this

```
some_very_longggg_variable_name_on_the_lhs = SomeLongClassNameIsHere.func_name(input_dt=some_default_input_dt_that_has_a_really_long_name_here)
```

I'm unable to change the names of the variables. The number of columns is 144 and I need to get it to 120.

It doesn't allow me to break it at the equal sign like the following and I also tried putting the argument of `func_name` on the next line, but `flake8` requires aligning the new line with the `(` on the previous line so that doesn't help. I'm not sure what else to do.

```
some_very_longggg_variable_name_on_the_lhs 
= SomeLongClassNameIsHere.func_name(input_dt=some_default_input_dt_that_has_a_really_long_name_here)
```

Comment: You can try using the backslash character before the operators.

Answer (score -1):

Python will not break a statement inside parentheses of any kind, so

```
a = (
    b
)
```

is the simplest, most legible and most maintainable way to do this.